# How to remove an object from list by a value

Tags: python-3.x

My problem is that I created a list of students with name and number. The task is now to remove a student by his number. My problem is that my code doesn't work.

Another problem is that it always shows the memory address instead of the value of the object.

Thanks in advance

class Student:

```
def __init__(self, name, number):
    self.name = name
    self.number = number
```

from .student import Student
class Course:

```
def __init__(self, name, code, credit, student_limit):
    self.name = name
    self.code = code
    self.credit = credit
    self.student_limit = student_limit

students = []
def add_student(self, new_student):
    self.student = new_student
    self.students.append(new_student)
    print("Student added" +str(self.students))

def remove_student_by_number(self, student_number):
    self.student_number = student_number
    if student_number in self.students: self.students.remove(student_number)
    print("Student removed" + str(self.students))
```

from .course import Course
class Department:

```
def __init__(self, name, code):
       self.name = name
       self.code = code

courses = []       
def add_course(self, course):
    self.course = course
    self.courses.append(course)
    print("Course added" +str(self.courses))
```

from python import *
def main():

```
alice = Student("Alice", 1336)
bob = Student("Bob", 1337)

math_dept = Department("Mathematics and Applied Mathematics", "MAM")

math_course = Course("Mathematics 1000", "MAM1000W", 1, 10)

math_dept.add_course(math_course)

math_course.add_student(bob)
math_course.add_student(alice)

math_course.remove_student_by_number(alice.number)

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.students` is a list of `Student` instance so it will print the instance's memory address if the method `__str__` is not implemented (see [here](https://www.journaldev.com/22460/python-str-repr-functions) for example). You should try to print each property like `student.name` or `student.number` explicitly.

Anyway you are trying to find `student_number` in list of `Student` so of course it will never run the remove line. Instead use `if student_number in [student.number for student in self.students]` which is looking up the student's number list, not the student list itself. However in this case, you also want to remove the student with the `student_number` as the input so you  may need to use a loop like this:

```
def remove_student_by_number(self, student_number):
    for student in self.students:
        if student.number == student_number:
            print("Student removed" + str(student.name))
            self.students.remove(student)
            break
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

But when I edit my code with "if student_number in [student.number for student in self.students] " I get a syntax error.

The method looks like this now:
    def remove_student_by_number(self, student_number):
        self.student_number = student_number
        if student_number in [student.number for student in self.students]
        print("Student removed" + str(self.students))